# How do I get the summation of every loop output in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

Instead of getting 1, 4, 9, 16, I want to get the sum of those numbers so basically I want 30 as my output. What changes do I need to make?

I've tried many things but the closest I've gotten to what I want is naming every output with a different int then increment the basenum then I've summed up the nums and the first result was correct but I kept getting continuous results after the initial one because of the loops.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       


    int basenum = 1;
    int exp = 2;//Irrelevant to the code, just a note for myself.
    metoda(basenum,exp);     
}

public static void metoda(int basenum, int sum) 
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
    {
          sum = basenum * basenum;
          basenum++;
          System.out.println(sum);  
     }      
  }
```

I expected to get the sum of every loop but instead I got the output of the loops.
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/14a5d4e143960f07dd1be548c683664975e536f8

Comment: Try `n·(n + 1)·(2n + 1) / 6`

Comment: It worked out, thank you!

Would you mind sharing who you got the formula from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the sum.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    int basenum = 1;
    int exp = 2;//Irrelevant to the code, just a note for myself.
    exp = metoda(basenum);     
}

public static void metoda(int basenum) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
    {
          sum += basenum * basenum;
          basenum++;
          System.out.println(sum);  
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
public static int metoda(int k) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
          sum += i * i; 
    }
    return sum;    
}
```

In your example you then have to call `metoda(4)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here: You need to add the result to the sum, and print AFTER the loop.

```java
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
{
    sum += basenum * basenum; // Changed
    basenum++;
}     
System.out.println(sum); // Changed
```

Comment: Okay that worked out, thank you! 

Could you tell me why you do "sum +=" instead of just "sum="?

The sum that I am getting is 32 but when I change the exp to 0, I get the result that I want which is surprising to me cause it shouldn't affect anything but it still changed the result, can you tell me why?

Comment: Well in your post you said "I want to get the sum of those numbers." Using `+=` will add to `sum` instead of overwriting its value. It is one of the "assignment operators" in Java. Your original code was overwriting `sum` every iteration. Does that help?